# How to read multiple Google Drive CSV files and append then in a single one with Python?

Tags: python, loops, csv, google-drive-api, append

I have multiple CSV files in a Google Drive folder and I want to concatenate them in a single one. There are a lot of them, that's why I'm requesting the API to get the files ID list and doing this Python `loop for` code to read and concatenate.

```
fileList = drive.ListFile({'q': "'1AtVlO3pL1OyP8yy02gWuAm9aMxOEWcnu' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
df_filelist_id = pd.DataFrame(fileList)
list_ov_id = df_filelist_id['id']

df_overview = []

for i in list_ov_id:
  downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':i})
  downloaded.GetContentFile('Filename.csv')
  df_ov = pd.read_csv('Filename.csv')
  df_overview.append(df_ov)

df_overview = pd.DataFrame(df_overview)
```

But that's the result:

```
FileNotDownloadableError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-8dbfd98f1ef9> in <module>()
      8 for i in list_ov_id:
      9   downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':i})
---> 10   downloaded.GetContentFile('Filename.csv')
     11   df_ov = pd.read_csv('Filename.csv')
     12   df_overview.append(df_ov)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pydrive/files.py in FetchContent(self, mimetype, remove_bom)
    263     else:
    264       raise FileNotDownloadableError(
--> 265         'No downloadLink/exportLinks for mimetype found in metadata')
    266 
    267     if mimetype == 'text/plain' and remove_bom:

FileNotDownloadableError: No downloadLink/exportLinks for mimetype found in metadata
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve it? Is there another better way?

Thx!

Comment: Is it a problem for you to download all the files and than just stick them together as one?

Comment: Hi, @Mibi! I solved it. There was a non csv file at the folder. I posted a new comment with the right version. Thanks a lot for your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

There was a non CSV files at the folder. By the way, I did some changes at the code. That's the final version:

```
listed = drive.ListFile({'q': "title contains '.csv' and 'FileOrFolderID' in parents"}).GetList()
list_id = []
list_title = []
for file in listed:
    list_id.append(file['id'])
    list_title.append(file['title'])

df = pd.DataFrame()

for id, title in zip(list_id, list_title):
    each_file = drive.CreateFile({'id': id})
    each_file.GetContentFile(title)
    df_each_file = pd.read_csv(title)
    df = df.append(df_each_file, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the samples from https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=zU5b6dlRwUQk

also check if the fileid, is a file or a folder. When trying to download files of different type we get this error. You can convert the file before trying the download

Comment: Hi, Mohammed! There was a non CSV file at the folder. A lot of work, stupid mistakes. I posted the right code bellow. Thanks for the colab link! It will be useful.